# When will the functions held by a hook be run in emacs?

Tags: emacs, hook, elisp

For example, I put some codes within `python-mode-hook`, and the codes will be run when:

(1) Every time I open a python file `*.py`

(2) Only the first time that `python-mode` was triggered

Does anyone have ideas that which answer is right?

Thanks!

Comment: As others pointed out, in the case of python-mode, it's every time you open a file in python-mode.  To do something only the first time, you would do (eval-after-load "python" '(progn (some-function) (setq some-var t))).  This runs just after python.el is loaded.

Comment: jpkotta: Noting, of course, that python.el could conceivably be loaded for some reason other than a call to `python-mode` (even if it might not be especially likely), so I'd be disinclined to rely upon that, if I very specifically wanted to act upon the first call to `python-mode`. There are other approaches that could be taken.

Comment: Annnd, there's not much sense in defining a hook to only run when a mode is first invoked, since that is already handled by `eval-after-load` and friends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no general rule about when hooks run: this is controlled solely by the code which defines the hook.  However, there are general conventions that are followed among which is this one:

- If `foo-mode` is a major mode of some sort, then `foo-mode-hook` will run each time `foo-mode` is enabled in a buffer.

In particular, as has already been pointed out, the functions in `python-mode-hook` run every time a `.py` file is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to look at the code, then note that the vast majority of major modes are constructed with the `define-derived-mode` macro (modes can simply supply `nil` for the `parent` if the new mode does not *actually* derive from another one, in order to still get the same benefits and standard behaviours from using the macro).

So <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `define-derived-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You'll see that the very last thing that happens when the mode is invoked is `(run-mode-hooks ',hook)` (where `,hook` in this instance will expand to the name of the mode with a `-hook` suffix).

So every time a buffer enables that mode (meaning that the mode function defined by that macro is executed), the mode's hook is also run (as well the hooks for any parent/ancestor modes -- the interesting `delay-mode-hooks` and `run-mode-hooks` interaction means that none of the hooks are run until all the other processing has been completed).

Answer (score 3):

It will run every time you open a python file.

Then python mode will be triggered for this file buffer and your hook will be executed.

You can easily test this by writing a simple hook:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook  (lambda () (message "python mode hook")))
```